# How to restore a SharePoint 2013 site to a Specific Content DB by SSOM C#?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, ssom

I have a `.bak` file of a SharePoint site. I want to restore it back. I am doing this with below code:

`var targetSiteCollection = webApp.Sites;`

`targetSiteCollection.Restore(this._siteUrl, backupFilename, true, true);`

Its working fine. But if I want to restore to a specific content DB, that option am not getting here.
However its possible with PowerShell SSOM where we can just pass the content DB name. Is there any available option in C# SSOM also to do so?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I found a work around here. There is no direct way to restore the SharePoint site to a specific content database, But we can move the site to the specific database once it is restored successfully. For this we have to do this:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        {
            var sitesToMove = new List<SPSite>
            {
                site
            };
            site.ContentDatabase.Move(targetDb, sitesToMove, out var failedSites);
        }
```